# Метод поиска и удаления одинаковых элементов в массиве

Tags: jquery, массивы, алгоритм, javascript

Появилась необходимость убрать все повторяющиеся элементы из массива, но при этом не сортировать его. Я реализовал в лоб и просто переписываю каждый элемент массива с конца и в новый массив и проверяю старый на наличие такого же элемента.

Вроде все работает, но я задумался о скорости т.к. такой метод должен быть весьма затратный и решил проверить его на jsperf. К моему удивлению тесты показали что мой метод выигрывает у метода, который я нашел в jquery (сначала отсортировать массив, а потом удалять все повторения, проходясь по всему массиву).

Но мне кажется что jsperf где то ошибается и по этому хочу поинтересоваться у более опытных коллег  почему получаются такие странные результаты:

http://jsperf.com/unique-test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@MrFranke](/users/4747/mrfranke)](/users/4747/mrfranke), у Вас массив

```
var arr = [2,3,1,3,4,2,7,92,4];
```

очень маленький.

По сути, когда Вы ищете дубликат в массиве, Вы делаете простую сорировку (с квадратичной сложностью). Широкоизвестно, что для маленьких (десятки элементов) массивов такой вид сортировки быстрее, чем любая "серьезная" (quicksort, mergesort (все виды, включая timsort) и т.п.) сортировка (из-за простоты алгоритма во внутреннем цикле сорировки исполняется мало команд).

Более того, во всех серьезных реализациях подобных сортровок в определенный момент (когда нужно отсортировать очередной небольшой отрезок данных) происходит переключение на квадратичную (Д. Кнут советует используют сортировку вставками) сортировку. Но в любом случае, обычно перед этим приходится совершать "массу телодвижений", которых в Вашем специфическом случае, естественно, нет.

Вот, собственно, и объяснение наблюдаемого эффекта. Вы видите, что O(n * n) < O(n * log n)

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение!
Может быть вы тогда подскажите как лучше всего организовать удаление одинаковых элементов в массиве без его сортировки? Т.е. что бы элементы остались на своих первоначальных местах.

Comment: В смысле, что из 

    arr = [2,3,1,3,4,2,7,92,4];

получается

    arr2 = [2,3,1,4,7,92];

так?

На С

    int j = 0, k;
    arr2[j++] = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n_arr; i++) {
       for (k = 0; k < j; k++)
         if (arr[i] == arr2[k])
           break;
       if (k == j)
          arr2[j++] = arr[i];
    }

теперь j это количество элементов в arr2.

Comment: @MrFranke, без сортировки (ну или без создания хэш-множества) быстрее квадрата не получится.

Answer (score 2):

Наиболее быстрым будет способ с использованием вспомогательного объекта:

```js
function returnUnique(arr) {
  var obj = new Object;
  for (var i = 0, i_max = arr.length; i < i_max; i++) {
    obj[arr[i]] = ''; // запоминаем элемент как свойство объекта
  }
  return Object.keys(obj);
}
```

Но этот способ работает корректно только с массивами из простых однородных элементов.

Comment: Использование объекта как словаря с ключами? Неплохо)